# Warning: .then() only excepts functions

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

in mean stack / nodejs / mongoose app, i have this code:

```html
User.findByIdAsync(req.params.id)
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(saveUpdates(req.body))
    .then(sendEmail())  // this is my addition
    .then(respondWithoutResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
```

the function sendMail looks like this:

```html
function sendEmail(body){
  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Excited User <admin@blabla.com>',
    to: 'johny@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'body text here'
  };

  var smtpConfig = {
    host: config.mailgun.smtp_host,
    port: 465,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {
        user: config.mailgun.smtp_user,
        pass: config.mailgun.smtp_pass
      }
    };

    
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);

    });
}
```

when i run it, i get an error:
Warning: .then() only excepts functions but was passed: [object Undefined]

what should i change in sendEmail in order for it to work with .then() ?

Comment: You need to pass a function that return a Promise, I guess.

Comment: thanks @trincot, that works, but then the spinning wheel does not stop... looks like something has not finished correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [`sendMail` supports promises](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#sending-mail), it can be as simple as this:

```
function sendEmail(body) {
  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Excited User <admin@blabla.com>',
    to: 'johny@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'body text here'
  };

  var smtpConfig = {
    host: config.mailgun.smtp_host,
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: config.mailgun.smtp_user,
      pass: config.mailgun.smtp_pass
    }
  };

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

  // Return the promise here.
  return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
}
```

If you want to maintain the logging, replace the last line with this:

```
return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then(function(info) {
  console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
  return info;
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
  throw error;
});
```

**EDIT**: I just noticed the `body` argument, which I'm guessing may be the result of `saveUpdates(req.body))`. If so, you need to restructure your promise chain a bit as well:

```
User.findByIdAsync(req.params.id)
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(saveUpdates(req.body))
    .then(sendEmail)
    .then(respondWithoutResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
```

Comment: it's working. unbelievable! but how is sendEmail gets the param? is it always the result of the previous function?

Comment: The parameter is the value that gets passed from the previous `.then()` step in the chain (that's basically how proper promise chains work). It's similar to `.then(function(body) { return sendEmail(body) })`